# Any negative effects of extending a well supply line pipe?

Tags: plumbing, well-pump

I have a shallow well with us single pipe supply line coming from the well directly to the above-ground jet pump. I want to change the position of the pump and that would require me to add a coupler and an extension to the pipe. My question is... will this have any negative effect, for example, on the flow rate.

Height of the pump won't change at all.
It'll only be moved about 6 ft. (further from well)

Comment: If within the length/distance rating for the pump, it should not.  It only adds another low possible leak source.

Comment: Jet pumps are usually 2 pipe where 1 line is the pressure to create the jet the other line is the water supply, single pipe shallow well pumps can only pull 1 ata at max usually a bit less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any effect, yes - more pipe, more pipe friction, or "total dynamic head" so less flow.

Enough to matter? It depends. If you are relocating the pump vertically higher, it will make a BIG difference for the suction side of a shallow well pump. There are very hard limits on that (~32 feet in pure theory, ~27 feet in engineering practice, typically, for "surface of water to pump.") Output correlates strongly with how far the water has to come up to the pump. Once a pump has pulled all the vacuum it can, the air can't push the water any higher or faster...which is how "suction" *actually* works. Pumps can push water far better than they can "pull" it (...make the air push it to them.)

Sideways 4-5 feet? Likely not noticeable. Sideways 100 feet - probably quite noticeable.

"Where *exactly* will it become noticeable/objectionable?"

You'd have to try it and see.

Comment: Totally agree start pulling a vacuum at 1 atmosphere so you could never reach the depth that would change water into a vapor.

Comment: Yeah, it's not changing in height at all, and only moving around 6 feet (further from well). Probably also going to upgrade from a 1/2 to 3/4 horsepower pump as well. Should offset.